# How to set up IE startup web page?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an e-machines desktop with Windows 7 and IE 11.  When we start up IE, it goes to a web page that has an advertisement in the middle of it and requires further URL entry to go to the desired web page.  How do we set it up so that when IE is started, it automatically goes to www.yahoo.com?

Comment: What have you tried already? Did the usual way not work or something?  See the MS help: [Change your home page for Internet Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/internet-explorer/change-home-page#ie=ie-11)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [these easy instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/change-home-page#ie=ie-11) to change your startup page:

1. Go to a page that you'd like to set as a home page.
2. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings.
   (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Settings.)
3. Tap or click Options, and under Home pages, tap or click Customize.
4. Tap or click Add current site, edit the URL if you'd like, and then tap or click Add to make the site one of your home pages.